# How can I use hashset to get unique values from an entity?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to remove the repeated course from the linq query below. When this query returns it returns multiples of the same course(s) but I would like for it to return unique courses. Can I use a hashset to make this list unique?  Thanks for any help!

```
 foreach (var course in Model.Assignments
                             .Select((x, y) => new { Data = x, Index = y })
                             .Where(x => x.Data.Ids == listOfIds[i]))
 { 
    // code here 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that understand you in 100 percent, but if you have any class you can override methods: **Equals** and **GetHashCode**, then you can use `Distinct()` for query.

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)